# При изменении select не меняется значение value

Tags: javascript, html

Вот смотрите, есть до боли простой код

```
<input type="text" id="q1">
<select id="q2">
    <option value="3">91</option>
    <option value="6">181</option>
    <option value="9">275</option>
    <option value="12">365</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="отразить" onclick="func()">
<div id="aa"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var sum = document.getElementById('q1').value;
    var days = document.getElementById('q2').value;

    function func(){
        document.getElementById('aa').innerHTML = (days);
    }    
</script>
```

Но у меня возник вопрос - почему при изменении селекта не изменяется значение value?

Т.е. скрипт всегда показывает именно то значение, которое выставлено при загрузке страницы, а как сделать так, чтобы при изменении `select` изменялось и значение `value`? Можно ли это сделать на js не вешая `onchange`?

Comment: А чем вас смущает onchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы получаете значение селекта только один раз, **до** выполнения функции `func`. Чтобы использовать актуальное значение *при нажатии на кнопку*, замените JS код на:

```
function func(){
    var sum = document.getElementById('q1').value;
    var days = document.getElementById('q2').value;

    document.getElementById('aa').innerHTML = (days);
}
```

А если же вам все-таки нужно вызывать `func` каждый раз при изменении значения в селекте, то без `onchange` события не обойтись.

Comment: Во как, спасибо, ваш код вполне подойдёт

Comment: Если я правильно ответил на вопрос, отметьте решение как "верное".